# firebug troubles during navigation

Tags: javascript, firefox, firebug

I have some problems with firebug :

1) how to remove this warning in permanence at the top of the console: "Warning:.. Enabling the Script panel causes a slow-down Firefox due to a platform bug This Will Be fixed with the next major Firefox and Firebug versions" ?

2) since this morning I have new warnings that appear "password fields present on a non-secure page (http://) This represents a security risk for theft login.." How to Delete this warning ?

3) the last few days, I have difficulty navigating, in fact, "Script" tab of firebug block the execution of javascript for no apparent reason (no breakpoint). It's unbearable and sometimes even blocking! How to explain this behavior and especially turn off?!

Thank you for helping me

PS: Firebug current version installed: 1.12.5

Comment: So a platform bug appears to be `no apparent reason` for you, that's cool :D